# How to import type information in module meant to be loaded in browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, module

I have a simple module that generates a React component:

```
// index.tsx

import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

....

ReactDOM.render(......);
```

react and react-dom are in directories in node_modules\@types.

I use the TypeScript compiler to compile this into a .js file. That .js file contains a module (because of the imports). I load that into an .html page:

```
<script type="module" src="./js/Views/Home/index.js"></script>
```

This compiles, and I get Intellisense and type checking. But Chrome (version 66) now throws an error in the console, saying

```
(index):1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

**I tried these options:**

1) Ambient variables

```
// this works for both compiler and browser, but doesn't give me type checking or intellisense
declare var ReactDOM: any;
declare var React: any;
```

2) No declarations at all

According to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types, this will pick up any @types declarations from node_modules in current dir, parent dir, etc.) Which sounds great, but it gives me the compiler error:

```
'ReactDOM' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

3) Triple-Slash Directive

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/react-dom/index.d.ts" />
```

Putting this at the top of the file also produced the compiler error

```
'ReactDOM' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

4) Specify types in tsconfig.json file

```
// Added to tsconfig.json, compilerOptions element
"types": [ "ReactDOM", "React" ]
```

The compiler now throws lots of "(TS) Duplicate identifier ...." error messages.

5) Directly import .d.ts files

```
import * as React from "../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts";
import * as ReactDOM from "../../node_modules/@types/react-dom/index.d.ts";
```

This gives me the compiler error:

```
An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing '../../node_modules/@types/react/index' instead.
```

6) Directly import the .d.ts files, but leave off the .d.ts extension

```
import * as React from "../../node_modules/@types/react/index";
import * as ReactDOM from "../../node_modules/@types/react-dom/index";
```

This compiles. But the browser now throws the error message:

```
index.tsx:1 GET http://localhost:8400/js/node_modules/@types/react/index 404 (Not Found)
index.tsx:2 GET http://localhost:8400/js/node_modules/@types/react-dom/index 404 (Not Found)
```

My question is, how can I import type information in a module that is to be loaded by the browser?

Comment: It seems you don't use a bundler, am I wrong? I think your problem might be solved by using webpack or another webbundler (rollup or fusebox for example). Webpack will handle all the import/export stuff, will generate one JS file, and you'll only have to load it and that's it, even for the dependencies like react.

Comment: You're right, my intent is to not use a bundler during development. This to speed up the edit-compile-run cycle.

Comment: If you load modules directly in the browser, should’t you load ALL your modules this way?

Comment: You do know that nowadays, bundlers come with a dev server that auorefreshes your code and deploy, don't you? I think you are walking around the best practices here. It will be far more complex to have one way for the dev and one way for the release/production build, than to use only one tool that'll do it all!

Comment: @Kokodoko Firstly, I would be happy to load all modules in the browser.  My question is how to make this work. It seems that the TypeScript compiler and Chrome don't work together. Secondly, I load the React modules to get the TypeScript codes in those modules. However, this is only needed at compile time, so I could do without loading those modules in the browser, if I could easily remove the imports from the compiled code.

Comment: @sjahan Can you point me to an article on how to make this work in a .Net Core web site running under IIS?

Comment: Modules have their own scope, making it impossible to communicate between modules that have no knowledge of each others existence. That means that a module loaded using `<script type="module" src="mymodule.js">` can only access other modules that were loaded the same way because the browser puts them all in the same scope. From these modules, you cannot access a module that was bundled at development time and loaded with `<script src="bundle.js">`. That bundle has its own internal scope which cannot be accessed from outside.

Comment: Was this resolved?